# any good html to excel converter like dompdf does

Tags: php, html, excel, dompdf, file-conversion

guys. Do you happen to know any good converter of html to excel file through php? I have seen lots (PHPExcel and SimpleExcel) but nothing can function the way dompdf does. (dompdf is a html to pdf converter through php)

Is there anything like dompdf in converting html (including its attributes e.g. strong, i, u) to excel? Please post.

Comment: Do you need CSS as well as inline styling?

Comment: Are you talking about converting an HTML document that consists of just a table? Excel is perfectly capable of opening something like this natively. Though it may not be able to capture all the document styling I've found it does a pretty good job.

Comment: @Mark Baker, yes sir. I also need CSS...

Comment: @BrianS, there are lots of software in converting HTML to Excel. But what I'm after is a converter invoked by PHP...

Comment: If you need CSS, then your choices are pretty much limited to nil. Inline styling will work, to an extent, with COM or PUNO or PHPExcel, but it's limited in all cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I've just served the HTML document as-is. Excel is perfectly capable of loading an HTML document and parsing it as a spreadsheet. Excel even understands many CSS attributes. All you have to do is add an Excel mime type to the HTTP headers, [for example](http://eclecticgeek.com/code/htmltable.php):

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition:Attachment;Filename=htmltable.htm');
readfile('htmltable.html');
```

Unfortunately this isn't as appealing an option as it used to be. Starting with Excel 2007 the program [performs some basic document type confirmation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx). Because HTML is not XLS (obviously) you get a warning. Excel can still open up the document and display it correctly, but there aren't really any options for disabling the warning.

You might try [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). I've never used it, but apparently you can use it to [convert a document from HTML to XLS](https://blog.mayflower.de/561-Import-and-export-data-using-PHPExcel.html):

> By combining the reader with the writer it is possible to convert
>   files from one format to another with just 3 lines of code:
>
> ```
> $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("XMLTest.xml");
> $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
> $objWriter->save('covertedXml2Xlsx.xlsx');
> ```

Comment: Sir @BrianS, thank you for your answer. I have researched more about my own topic -- coverting HTML to Excel through PHP -- and it seems I have found the solution, thanks to you sir.


 <?php
 header('Content-type: application/excel');                                  
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xlsx"');
 ?>
 
 <table border = "1">
 <tr><td>Whatever the style and content will be shown in excel :D</td></tr>
 </table>

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours setting up an automated report using PHPExcel and found it incredibly unwieldy. I found it much more user-friendly and effective to write the data to .csv (fputcsv), then use COM to run an Excel macro, which opens the .csv and implements all the formatting, etc.

You can also execute Excel macros from VBScript and call PHP's exec function to run the VBScript.

Answer (score -1):

[fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) Is what you after. Easy if you have info before it gets to html. Can also add fancy stuff like skip columns/rows and make headings, make pages.

Comment: fputcsv is quite incapable of handling styling, which is one of the OPs prerequisites

Comment: i've researched about fputcsv but it seems it cannot handle styling... although it is a good one for having simple excel files only.. :D